# Tensorflow tf.constant_initializer is very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, word2vec

Trying to use pre trained word2vec embeddings of 100 dim for training a LSTM

```
@staticmethod
def load_embeddings(pre_trained_embeddings_path, word_embed_size):
    embd = []
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    cnt = 4
    with codecs.open(pre_trained_embeddings_path, mode="r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            values = line.strip().split(' ')
            embd.append(values[1:])
            cnt += 1
            if cnt % 100000 == 0:
                print("word-vectors loaded: %d" % cnt)

    embedding, vocab_size, embed_dim = embd, len(embd), len(embd[0])

    load_end_time = time.time()
    print("word vectors loaded from and start initialising, cnt: %d, time taken: %d secs " % (vocab_size, load_end_time - start_time))

    embedding_init = tf.constant_initializer(embedding, dtype=tf.float16)
    src_word_embedding = tf.get_variable(shape=[vocab_size, embed_dim], initializer=embedding_init, trainable=False, name='word_embedding', dtype=tf.float16)

    print("word-vectors loaded and initialised, cnt: %d, time taken: %d secs" % (vocab_size, time.time() - load_end_time))

    return src_word_embedding
```

And the output of this when running this method is like :

```
word vectors loaded from and start initialising, cnt: 2419080, time taken: 74 secs
word-vectors loaded and initialised, cnt: 2419080, time taken: 1647 secs
```

system info: `tensorflow 1.1.0, tcmalloc, python 3.6, ubuntu 14.04`

HALF an hour to initialize seems to be very slow or is it a normal behavior ? Any idea what could be the issue or is there one ?

UPDATE: using @sirfz method of supplying the embeddings made it really fast to load the embeddings `Initialization Done in 85 secs`

Comment: It seems to be an open issue. Refer to [Boolean operations on GPU are extremely slow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3649).

Comment: yes similar times with float32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading large constants into a graph is not only slower, it also leaks lots of memory. I had a similar issue which [I reported not long ago](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9742) and the best workaround for me was:

```
# placeholder for loading your saved embeddings
embedding_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, shape=[vocab_size, embed_dim])
src_word_embedding = tf.get_variable(initializer=embedding_init, trainable=False, name='word_embedding', dtype=tf.float16)

# run initialization with the value of embeddings placeholder
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={embedding_init: embedding})
```

Comment: will this save the embeddings when saving a checkpoint and will this load back the original embeddings on restore ?

Comment: DAMN this reduced the times by crazy amount

```Initialization Done in 85 secs```

Comment: I had the same reaction when I first tried it as well ;) as for the checkpoint I believe it'll work normally since it'll just serialize the variables as is. I personally prefer dumping the variables using `numpy.save` instead of check points since it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether this is an intended behavior, but I can explain why is it can slow on a small example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
a = tf.constant(x, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(x, name='b')
c = a + b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    writer.close()
```

When you initialize the constant, the value of this constant is added to the graph. If you will open the graph you can see it by clicking on the `a` value.

[image]

In my case it was a 2x2 matrix, but it looks like in your case it is 2M x ? matrix, which is huge. So in my opinion this is the reason for such a slow execution.

Try to initialize this as a variable and feed you embedding there.

Comment: Exactly, it's serializing the large tensor into a node in the graph which is the main source of the slowness (and ultimately the larger memory footprint). Using the workaround in my answer avoids this expensive serialization step.